# deploying EJB over JBoss 7.1

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I'm deploying a really simple helloworld style EJB application.  When doing so I get...

```
WARNING: -logmodule is deprecated. Please use the system property 'java.util.logging.manager' or the 'java.util.logging.LogManager' service loader.
13:15:54,638 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
13:15:55,094 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
13:15:55,175 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
13:15:56,587 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
13:15:56,592 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
13:15:56,602 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
13:15:56,614 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.2.GA
13:15:56,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
13:15:56,661 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
13:15:56,707 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
13:15:56,793 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.7.Final)
13:15:56,822 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
13:15:56,839 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
13:15:56,881 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
13:15:56,889 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
13:15:56,898 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:15:56,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.6.final
13:15:56,989 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
13:15:57,324 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.1.GA
13:15:57,501 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
13:15:58,264 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /usr/bin/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments
13:15:58,265 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
13:15:58,265 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
13:15:58,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found HelloWorld.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called HelloWorld.war.dodeploy
13:15:58,581 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/EjbMySql] 

13:15:58,589 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started (with errors) in 4548ms - Started 131 of 204 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 70 services are passive or on-demand)
```

It looks like I need to add an include somewhere, my code is very simple...

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import model.MyUser;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @EJB HelloBean bean;
    @PersistenceUnit
    EntityManagerFactory emF;
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("<html><body>");
        MyUser user = (MyUser)emF.createEntityManager().createQuery("select * from  myuser").getResultList().get(0);
        out.println("Username = " + user.getName());
        out.print("</body></html>");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Persistance.xml is shown below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="HelloWorld">
        <jta-data-source>EjbMySql</jta-data-source>
        <class>model.MyUser</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

modules/com/mysql/main/Modules.xml is as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  ~ JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source.
  ~ Copyright 2010, Red Hat, Inc., and individual contributors
  ~ as indicated by the @author tags. See the copyright.txt file in the
  ~ distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
  ~
  ~ This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
  ~ under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
  ~ published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of
  ~ the License, or (at your option) any later version.
  ~
  ~ This software is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  ~ MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
  ~ Lesser General Public License for more details.
  ~
  ~ You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
  ~ License along with this software; if not, write to the Free
  ~ Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
  ~ 02110-1301 USA, or see the FSF site: http://www.fsf.org.
  -->

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql.jdbc">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Standalone.xml has the following entry...

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
           <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/EjbMySql" pool-name="EjbMySql" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ejbdb</connection-url>
                <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>root</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
    <drivers>
            <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql.jdbc"> <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class> </driver>
        </drivers>
        </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

In my project, I have the MySQL jar in /WebContent/META-INF/services/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: Tried...

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/EjbMySql" pool-name="EjbMySql" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ejbdb</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
```

comes back with the same error.

Comment: Try changing your driver name to "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver".

Comment: tried this, updated question, didn't fix anything though :<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `<JBOSS_HOME>/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` find the `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">` tag and add the following inside the `<datasources>` element:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS" pool-name="MysqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASE_NAME</connection-url>
        <driver>com.mysql</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>USERNAME</user-name>
            <password>PASSWORD</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
            <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

Replace DATABASE_NAME,USERNAME and PASSWORD apporpriately.

Inside the `<drivers>` element add the following:

```
<driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

Now, go to `<JBOSS_HOME>/modules` and create the path `com/mysql/main`put the driver's jar there (eg. mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar) and create the file `module.xml` with the following contents:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I did as you suggested but I get the error... http://pastebin.com/5rRPnSKu and all the XML is syntactically correct as it opens in chrome etc fine.  standalone.xml is http://pastebin.com/S8esfvxC

Comment: You should put the <datasource> tag inside the <datasources> element. I have edited my answer

Comment: copied this and still get exactly the same error mate.  JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.com_mysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS]

Comment: @david99world are you sure you configured com.mysql module as stated in my answer? It seems that JBoss cannot find it.

Comment: Excellent, it works better when I have module.xml instead of modules.xml !!! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to associate the datasource in standalone.xml with the driver-module like in the example below (taken from [here](http://planet.jboss.org/view/post.seam;jsessionid=29C2F625975E161257386C5FB9258C13?post=how_to_create_and_manage_datasources_in_as7):

```
     <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="H2DS">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <pool></pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
                <validation></validation>
                <timeout></timeout>
                <statement></statement>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql.jdbc"> <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class> </driver>
            </drivers>
      </datasources>
```

The driver-element in datasources herein references a driver definition in the drivers-element, which in itself references the module that you defined and the classes. That is how I use it, and it works for me on JBoss 7.1.

Comment: Hi, changed my code (as you can see from above) to have this set in the standalone.xml but it still has the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: @david99world According to your module.xml, the name of your module is com.mysql, not the com.mysql.jdbc that you reference in standalone.xml

Comment: I agree. <module ... name="com.mysql.jdbc"> so that it matchs <driver ... module="com.mysql.jdbc"

Comment: ah, sorry changed the XML but I still get the same problem, updated question to reflect this.

Comment: You might also want to try changing your persistence.xml to <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/EjbMySql</jta-data-source>. If there is still an issue, in your module.xml add a dependency to javax.transactions.api. There was a bug at one point where that was missing, though I think it was fixed before 7.1.0.Final.

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss 7, several configuration details changed for creating a data source and installing a JDBC driver. Take a look at this migration [guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7), in the sections "Define the datasource" and "Install the JDBC driver".

Comment: Ah, I don't have a /server directory in my jboss_home, I have appclient, bin, bundles, docs, domain, modules, standalone, welcome-content

Comment: I updated my answer. I had forgotten that in JBoss 7 the directory structure changed quite a bit.

Comment: Ah, as far as I can tell, everything should be correct, the jar is in /webcontent/meta-inf/services as required, the manifest and standalone xml files are up to date too.

Answer (score 0):

Is the version of driver. Change for a new version. Believe, is only it!!!
I changed the driver mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar   to   mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar, then the problem is solved.