# Jboss 7 - Oracle Datasource not working

Tags: oracle, persistence, datasource, jboss7.x, ojdbc

I'm working on a Web App with just one WAR project. It uses JPA and has a DataSource that I need to configure to run on **JBOSS 7**. The database is **Oracle**.

I'm getting this error:

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jboss.jdbc.batchAdminDB
```

I've followed instructions for using dataSource on Jboss. So I have these configurations:

**{JBOSS_HOME}/modules/com/oracle/ojdbc6/main/module.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api" />
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

ojdbc6.jar exists and the name is correct.

**standalone.xml**

```xml
<datasources>

                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/batchAdminDB" pool-name="batchAdminDB" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT/xe</connection-url>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>USER</user-name>
                        <password>PASSW</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
                        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

On the application:
META-INF/**persistence.xml:**

```xml
<persistence-unit name="batchAdminEM" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/jdbc/batchAdminDB</jta-data-source>

    <class>...</class>
 ...</persistence-unit>
```

When Jboss starts (without the app) it get to read(bound) the datasource. The error comes when I try to deploy the app, it doesn't run.

More of StackTrace to help:

```
15:57:46,888 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/jdbc/batchAdminDB]
...
15:57:52,356 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: batchAdminEM
    ...]
15:57:53,649 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 13255ms - Started 325 of 568 services (165 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
15:57:53,861 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "BatchAdmin.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.BatchAdmin.BatchAdmin.env.jboss.jdbc.batchAdminDBjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jboss.jdbc.batchAdminDBMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.module.BatchAdmin.BatchAdmin.env.jboss.jdbc.batchAdminDBjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jboss.jdbc.batchAdminDB]"]}
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jboss.jdbc.batchAdminDB (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.BatchAdmin.BatchAdmin.env.jboss.jdbc.batchAdminDB] 

15:57:53,934 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.BatchAdmin.BatchAdmin.env.jboss.jdbc.batchAdminDBjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jboss.jdbc.batchAdminDBMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.module.BatchAdmin.BatchAdmin.env.jboss.jdbc.batchAdminDBjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jboss.jdbc.batchAdminDB]"]}}}
```

Comment: I've seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481510/deploying-ejb-over-jboss-7-1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102826/unable-to-define-oracle-datasource-on-jboss-as-7 and others but none of then worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time I found what was the problem.

**web.xml** contains a configuration that was used before, on Tomcat.

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jboss/jdbc/batchAdminDB</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
```

This configuration was probally confusing Jboss. It's not necessary anymore.

The solution:
 Just comment or remove that part (resource-ref).

A helpful link (in portuguese):
http://www.guj.com.br/java/256103-resolvido-seam-3--hibernate-4--jbossas7-erro-de-datasource

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong connection URL format. With `xe` as SID, you must either use:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:xe
```

or

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//HOST:PORT/xe
```

Check [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC) for more information.

ADD

You also have to change one line in your module.xml file in this way:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
```

Comment: Hi Reza. I've changed it as you said, but the error continues the same.

Comment: Hi @Reicardo, I think I had the same problem a while ago and it was because of some extra unwanted spaces in my module.xml file. I eventually ended up copying a file from one of the working modules and then changing the content carefully so as not to add any additional spaces. Additionally, I think the correct Driver class name must be "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver". Try these two and see what happens next.

Comment: Thanks for helping @Reza. I re-checked the strings in each config file. They are ok. I also changed oracle driver class. Problem persists

Comment: @Ricardo: you should change the module.xml file as well. see above!